# Detect page resolution and load specific page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying a way to open a page after that I know the page resolution.

I wish to load the correct page on mobiles phone

Here the code which does not work as expected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;

function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = null;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","prova.php?width="+width+"&height="+height+"&data="+(Math.random()*1000),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload = loadXMLDoc();

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDIV"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the question? Aside from the part where I wonder if this is the right way to serve different content for mobile / desktop, I don't see any obvious problems.

Comment: you should look into css media queries, thats how this kind of thing is handled nowadays

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that the code does not works!

Comment: Definitely not my preffered way of doing it. I recommend either using a PHP package such as `http://mobiledetect.net/` or as @andrew suggested, use css media queries.

Comment: it does not load the page

Comment: I think that the css media queries may be the best solutions... thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You need to remove the () from loadXMLDoc();

```
window.onload = loadXMLDoc;
```

Assigning an event handler using a function like you do, assumes that the function you call returns a function. If you remove the () you replace the event handler with your function.

Alternatively use an anonymous function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // here is the code you want to execute on load
}
```

**2.**

You really need to look at [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) as mentioned by Yani in a comment